# How to compute the joint probability of two sequences?

Tags: python, probability

Given two lists of letters:

```py
x = [A, B, D, A, D, D, ...]
y = [D, F, C, C, B, B, ...]
```

How can I compute the probability `p(x_i = B, x_(i+1) = D, y_i = F)`, where `i` represents a generic index in the corresponding list?

Comment: so x and y can have any upper letter from English alphabet?

Comment: Without further knowledge of mathematical properties of the lists you just iterate through all possible "i", count how often the requested letter combination appears and divide it by number of possible "i" values.

Answer (score 1):

Using the arrays you've given, you could use numpy arrays for convenience, as

```
import numpy as np
N=len(x)
xi=(np.array(x)=='B').astype(int)
xip=np.roll((np.array(x)=='D').astype(int),-1) # shift array one forward, and convert boolean to integer (True=1, False=0)
yi=(np.array(y)=='F').astype(int)
prob=(xi+xip+yi==3).astype(int)[0:N-1].sum()/(N-1)
```

where prob is the probability desired.